# extract the value AutoNumeric.getAutoNumericElement()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-events

I'm having trouble figuring out how to extract the value I need from the input via the name attribute. This is my html code below
`

```
<tr class="" id="">
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding: .25rem;" class="isCoin">
                            <input hidden="" name="DisposableBagAmountList[0].DenominationStructure.DenominationStructureItems[5].IsCoin" wfd-invisible="true">
                        </td>

                        <td class="text-right w-50" style="vertical-align: middle; padding: .25rem;">
                            <input hidden="" name="DisposableBagAmountList[0].DenominationStructure.DenominationStructureItems[5].Id" value="1" wfd-invisible="true">
                            <input class="denominationStructureNumber" id="DenominationStructureItems[5].FaceValue" hidden="" name="DisposableBagAmountList[0].DenominationStructure.DenominationStructureItems[5].FaceValue" value="10.0000" readonly="" wfd-invisible="true">
                            <div class="faceValue">
10                            </div>
                        </td>

                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding: .25rem;">x</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding: .25rem;">
                            <input class="denominationStructureNumber text-right form-control" style="min-width:80px" name="DisposableBagAmountList[0].DenominationStructure.DenominationStructureItems[5].Count" value="0" onchange="changeTotalDenominationItemsAmount()">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

And I will have in this name="DisposableBagAmountList[n].DenominationStructure.DenominationStructureItems[m].FaceValue" values like DisposableBagAmountList[0], then [1] .. [n] The same this is with DenominationStructureItems[0], then [1] .. [5]
This is my function then need to calculate all FaceValue with Numbers and give me total, for two or more diffrent denominationStructures.

```
function {
var total = 0;
debugger;
const numbers = $(document).find('input\[name$=".Count"\]');
//const faceValueNumbers = $(document).find('input\[name$=".FaceValue"\]');

    for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        //old one DenominationStructure[5].CurrencyDenominationFaceValue
        //DisposableBagAmountList[0].DenominationStructure.DenominationStructureItems[5].FaceValue
        var faceValueNumbers = $(document).find('input[name$=".DenominationStructureItems[' + i + '].FaceValue"]');
        //DenominationStructureItems[0].FaceValue.denominationStructureNumber
        for (var j = 0; j < faceValueNumbers.length; j++) {
    
            //var faceValue = $(document).find('input[id="DenominationStructure[' + i + '].FaceValue"]')[j];
            var faceValue = $(document).find('input[id="DenominationStructure[' + i + '].FaceValue"]');
            //   $(document).find('input[id="DenominationStructure[' + i + '].FaceValue"]')[j];
    
            var anFaceValue = AutoNumeric.getAutoNumericElement(faceValue);
    
            var anElement = AutoNumeric.getAutoNumericElement(numbers[i]);
    
            total += anFaceValue.getNumber() * anElement.getNumber();
        }        
    }
    
    var anTotal = AutoNumeric.getAutoNumericElement('#totalDenominationAmount');
    if (anTotal) anTotal.set(total);

}
```

Basically, anFaceValue is always null for me, so I don't know how to extract the value from the input.

Does someone knows where I am wrong?

Thank you.

I am trying to extract the value for that facevalue via attr name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what needs to be done, I have to separate it first because I have two denominational structures, that is the index that I pass, after that I find all the elements under it and calculate. In the end, I pass as many times as I have indexes.
Here is a sample code

```
    const changeTotalDenominationItemsAmount = (disposableBagIndex) => {
    var total = 0;
    
    if (AutoNumeric.getAutoNumericElement('#totalDenominationAmount_' + disposableBagIndex) === null) {
        new AutoNumeric('#totalDenominationAmount_' + disposableBagIndex, { decimalPlaces: '2', decimalCharacter: ',', digitGroupSeparator: '.', readOnly: true });
    }

    if (AutoNumeric.getAutoNumericElement('#denominationStructureCount_' + disposableBagIndex) === null && AutoNumeric.getAutoNumericElement('#denominationStructureFaceValue_' + disposableBagIndex) === null) {

        AutoNumeric.multiple('#denominationStructureFaceValue_' + disposableBagIndex, { decimalPlaces: '4', decimalCharacter: ',', digitGroupSeparator: '.' });
        AutoNumeric.multiple('#denominationStructureCount_' + disposableBagIndex, { decimalPlaces: '0', decimalCharacter: ',', digitGroupSeparator: '.' });
    }

    var tableStructure = $("#denominationStructure_" + disposableBagIndex);
    const numbers = $(tableStructure).find('input[name^="DisposableBagAmountList[' + disposableBagIndex + ']"][name$=".Count"]');
    
    for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

        var faceValue = $(tableStructure).find('input[name$="DenominationStructureItems[' + i + '].FaceValue"]')[0];

        var anFaceValue = AutoNumeric.getAutoNumericElement(faceValue);

        var anElement = AutoNumeric.getAutoNumericElement(numbers[i]);

        total += anFaceValue.getNumber() * anElement.getNumber();
    }

    var anTotal = AutoNumeric.getAutoNumericElement('#totalDenominationAmount_' + disposableBagIndex);
    if (anTotal) anTotal.set(total);
}
```

keep in mind that the input html tag is like this

```
<input id="denominationStructureFaceValue_0" class="denominationStructureFaceValue" hidden name="DisposableBagAmountList[0].DenominationStructure.DenominationStructureItems[0].FaceValue" value="10.0000" readonly="" />

<input id="denominationStructureCount_0" class="denominationStructureCount text-right form-control" style="min-width:80px" name="DisposableBagAmountList[0].DenominationStructure.DenominationStructureItems[0].Count" value="10.0000" onchange="changeTotalDenominationItemsAmount(0)" />
```

and everything works together with autonumeric perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting the faceValue from `DenominationStructureItems` and not `DenominationStructure`?

Is the loop iterating? Maybe add some alerting or logs to figure it out.